# ANT - How to copy a group of files maintaining the Linux permissions

Tags: ant, copy, execute, cp, fileset

I need to copy a group of files with ant.
Unfortunately I can't use the target "copy" because it loses the Linux file permissions. So must use the target "execute" "cp" . 
How can I pass a group of file to the execute cp target? I know that I have to use a fileset but in which manner I can pass a fileset as argument of the execute cp target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass filesets to operating system commands. The best you can do is use the [apply](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) task to invoke the "cp" command on each file as follows:

```
  <apply executable="cp">
     <srcfile/>
     <targetfile/>
     <fileset dir="src" includes="*.txt"/>
     <globmapper from="*.txt" to="output/*.txt"/>
  </apply>
```

But, I don't really understand why you couldn't combine the [copy](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) task with [chmod](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/chmod.html), it would be most efficient:

```
<copy todir="output">
  <fileset dir="src" includes="*.txt"/>
</copy>

<chmod perm="700">
  <fileset dir="output" includes="*.txt"/>
</chmod>
```

Comment: I can't use the second target (the one with chmod perm="700") because not all the file that I want to copy have the same permissions and I would like to preserve the original pattern of each one. 
In any case the first target that you posted works perfectly. Thanks very very much it's a lot of time that I search for a solution to this problem. :)